# Codeigniter:Image not shows in page

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I am displaying an image like this way

```
<?php foreach($result $as $items){

  echo '<img src="<?php echo $items['hoteldetail']['images']['image']['imagepath']; ?>" >';
}
```

But it dosen't show the image when i check the source it is mixed with **localhost address**

Here is the thing i will get from the inspect element

> localhost/holiday/hotel/cdn.travelpartnerweb.com/DesiyaImages/Image/1/nxd/maw/qyj/ibt/HO.jpg

But actually the this is the image url

> cdn.travelpartnerweb.com/DesiyaImages/Image/1/nxd/maw/qyj/ibt/HO.jpg

Why this is happening?

Comment: can u provide config_url of config.php file?

Comment: could you please dump $result array ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($result $as $items){

  echo '<img src="http://'. $items['hoteldetail']['images']['image']['imagepath'] .'" >';// mark http:// here
}
```

**source it is mixed with localhost address**

Please enter `http://` either manually or update your database and remember to enter it next time when you use a new url other then `base url`

Answer (score 1):

You are using  inside echo. Try like below:

```
echo '<img src="//'.$items['hoteldetail']['images']['image']['imagepath'].'" >';
```

Comment: @BlessanKurien Ok, i have updated my answer. Check like that.

Comment: @BlessanKurien If my answer will work for you then please accept it so other one not west there time to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add `http://` protocol in your image source for external web access:

```
<?
foreach($result $as $items){
?>
  <img src="http://<?=$items['hoteldetail']['images']['image']['imagepath'];?>">
<?php
}
?>
```